# Mongo Aggs and total count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I experiencing some trouble in mongodb to do a query on collection to get all documents filtered, paginate(with skip and limit) and get the total count like that

The chat document look like that:

```
{
"_id": "c603db3e75ec76f5a4dff559bc525e29",
"members": [{
  "user": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
  "status": "creator"
}, {
  "user": "5b31dc3f88284a009fa847e5",
  "status": "member"
}],
"messages": [{
  "_id": 2,
  "from": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
  "parse_mode": "none",
  "text": "fffasdfsa",
  "attachment": null,
  "time": 1529995684119,
  "type": "text"
},
{...},
{...}
]}
```

And i would like to get result like that

```
{
  total_count: 3,
  chats: [{
    "_id": "c603db3e75ec76f5a4dff559bc525e29",
    "members": [{
      "user": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "status": "creator"
    }, {
      "user": "5b31dc3f88284a009fa847e5",
      "status": "member"
    }],
    "creator": {
      "user": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "status": "creator"
    },
    "lastMessage": {
      "_id": 4,
      "from": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "parse_mode": "none",
      "text": "aasdas",
      "attachment": null,
      "time": 1529995698736,
      "type": "text"
    },
    "messages": [{
      "_id": 2,
      "from": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "parse_mode": "none",
      "text": "fffasdfsa",
      "attachment": null,
      "time": 1529995684119,
      "type": "text"
    }, {
      "_id": 3,
      "from": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "parse_mode": "none",
      "text": "weqw",
      "attachment": null,
      "time": 1529995690015,
      "type": "text"
    }, {
      "_id": 4,
      "from": "5b2b0d5135cfd60185034bf6",
      "parse_mode": "none",
      "text": "aasdas",
      "attachment": null,
      "time": 1529995698736,
      "type": "text"
    }]
  },
  {...},
  {...}
  ]
}
```

My query is

```
collection<DbChat>('chats').aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    messages: { $exists: true }
                }
            },
            { $unwind: '$messages' },
            { $unwind: '$members' },
            { $group: {_id: '$_id', members:  { $push: '$members' },  member:  { $last: '$members' }, creator:  { $first: '$members' }, messages: {$push: '$messages' } , lastMessage: {$last: '$messages'}}},
            { $sort: this.sort},
        ]}.skip(skip).limit(size)
```

with this query i dont get the total_count I tried lot of things but i didnt found a way to get the result and the count in the same query.

Thanks